# QGIS Processing not loading - error on startup

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, osgeo4w, qgis-3

After installing both QGIS 2.18.17 and QGIS 3.0 in parallel using OSGeo4W the processing framework/toolbox etc. no longer loads in QGIS 2.18.17 (or other earlier than 3.0 version) when starting QGIS.

I have tried various combinations of reinstalling, uninstalling and using different versions, to no avail.

This is the error message I get:

```
warning:C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py:607: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\test': missing __init__.py
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\__init__.py", line 52, in classFactory
            from bufferbypercentage import BufferByPercentagePlugin
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\bufferbypercentage.py", line 36, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 62, in <module>
            from processing.algs.saga.SagaAlgorithmProvider import SagaAlgorithmProvider
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithmProvider.py", line 33, in <module>
            from SagaAlgorithm import SagaAlgorithm
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 20, in <module>
            standard_library.install_aliases()
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py", line 483, in install_aliases
            import test
```

and ... :

```
1   Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 37, in classFactory
            from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py", line 38, in <module>
            from processing.gui.ProcessingToolbox import ProcessingToolbox
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 31, in <module>
            from qgis.PyQt import uic
        ImportError: cannot import name uic
```

Are there any recommended ways to fix this problem so that processing will still work with QGIS 2.xxx?

Answer (score 1):

Try launching QGIS 2 through the bat file in the OSGeo4W folder:

`C:\OSGeo4W64\bin`

`qgis-ltr.bat`

This will set the correct environmental variables and processing should work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: I have a similar problem on WIN 7: QGIS 3.0 does not load Processing (and neither the python concole). The developer version of QGIS (3.1xxx) instead has no problem at all.